# how can i print monopoly money on the both pages

Tags: print-design

how can I print money of monopoly on one paper in order below (A,B,C,D,E,F... there are images of different monopoly money that I want print on one side and / means Enter key on keyboard)

A   B/C   D/E   F/G   H

on the back of paper (I want to print exactly same image belong to front pages)

A   B/C  D/E   F/G   H

thanks for helping

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking… just print on both sides of the paper, presumably. What exactly is it you can’t figure out?

Comment: Simply reverse the order for the back side....

Comment: Which program are you using? What kind of files do you have?

Answer (score 1):

If you want each reverse to line up with the same note on the front, then reverse your note order...

| Front | Back |
| --- | --- |
| A B | B A |
| C D | D C |
| E F | F E |
| G H | H G |

Comment: is there any command in photoshop that do this? I will try this with the crop but I hope there be a better solution

Comment: No, this is a manual layout task. If each is on a separate layer, Ps will help you with guide/snap but it won't do it for you.

Comment: +1 In cases like this, if a layout program is available, I usually use it: most DTP/Layout software handles "linking" and  so if the OP were to lay this out, they will tend to have more precise positioning control, and if they modify the items for design purposes (say C & F), they only need to "refresh link" instead of re-laying out the affected sections. There are open source options if inDesign isn't available. PS does support linking, but the last time I tried this using AI files linked to PS, PS didn't support "live links"